# What are AO / NM / D / SG texture name equivalents in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, materials

I'm not a modeler and i don't know how to match each texture with the requested ones by the material.

In one side i got unity:

[image]

And in the other, this model textures:

[image]

The only references that i found online were:

- AO => Ambient Occlusion - Occlusion
- NM => Normal Map - Normal Map
- sg => ?
- d => Diffuse?Displacement? - ?

Comment: These abbreviations aren't fully standardized. Can you tell us a bit more about the source of these textures? That may help us isolate what nomenclature they're using. In particular, "sg" is probably some form of "specularity / smoothness / glossiness," but there are a good half-dozen different ways to handle this type of material information so we'd need to know more to be able to apply it correctly as intended in a new material.

Comment: What exactly do you need? I tried doing what you said, switching to specular setup and setting sg as Albedo, model looks correct now.